# Running command-line processes in parallel in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line, parallel-processing, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS, a command-line tool, to render images of websites, and I want to run a number of these in parallel instead of doing one after the other. How can I do this?

Comment: You could simply use Thread.new do... end

Comment: cool, how does this compare to the solution provided by the first answer?

Comment: and what about using fibers instead of threads?

Comment: first answer is out of topic, it's for queuing jobs which is not what you asked for. Fibers are great, just lighter parallel processing, maybe more adapted to your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an Example using [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).  Note I've left escaping out for brevity... you should *never* pass external inputs directly into shell commands.

```
class RasterizeWebPageJob
  @queue = :screenshots
  def self.perform(url)
    system("/usr/bin/env DISPLAY=:1 phantomjs rasterize.js #{url} ...")
  end
end

10.times { Resque.enqueue(RasterizeWebPageJob, "http://google.com/") }
```

Provided you're running enough workers (and there are workers available), they'll execute in parallel.  The important thing here is that you put separate jobs onto the queue instead of processing multiple screenshots from within the one job.

I'd advise against using `Thread.new` in a Rails controller.  Queues are much easier (and safer) to manage than Threads.

Comment: and what are the differences?

Comment: Performance will likely be worse, since you need to be running Resque, which adds process overhead, though it does use a fast forking model. Threads would honestly be a bad idea... they share the same memory space, which, if you're not experienced in writing multithreaded programs can cause some very hard to find bugs.  If one thread crashes, your entire process will crash and it will be hard to identify what had run and what hadn't.  Resque (and other queueing solutions) is specific designed to make managing long running jobs easier and more chaos-friendly.

Comment: to add to what d11wtq said, ruby threads aren't "real" threads anyway. they don't truly run in parallel, so you're probably better off with resque

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it. What you are looking for is to do asynchronous jobs in the background. This video may help: http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling

Comment: nice... so if I ran an `each` loop in a worker that iterated over a number of shell commands, they would run in parallel?

Comment: and would the each loop need to go inside the worker or around where you call the worker?

Answer (score 0):

I think what these other answers may be missing is providing a basic education on a design pattern that you'll want to use. Yes, Resque or Starling and Workling or Resque combined with Foreman will be great solutions, but you'll probably want to know why.

I believe the pattern you'll want to use is the Observer Pattern or Publisher-Subscriber or PubSub, for short. The idea is similar to how a printer might work, in the simplest case.

A person (publisher) clicks print in say, a web browser. Then, asynchronously, the printer prints them. The printer, if it's not on, will pick up the messages when it turns on. If multiple people send documents to the printer, the printer will select them in order (FIFO) and then process (print) them. If there are multiple printers listening to the same queue (this is where the metaphor breaks down since you usually don't have that), then they can select messages in turn to process the queue faster.

Resque and other PubSub gems, projects, JARs (you're not limited to Ruby) implement this design pattern.

More info about the pattern here (note that the Java Observable is a class which is a bad design decision. You can implement your own):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern

For our processing, we use Resque for smaller tasks, but you're still limited to global interpreter lock and other issues like having to deploy your code to a server, install gems, etc. We now use Storm (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) to handle our stream processing and it works way better. Storm may be overkill for what you're trying to do, depending on how many images you're processing in a day.